# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to build a small script to download videos.I'm facing problem when trying to pass integer into subprocess.call  Thank you in advance

```
# test url for analysis
URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WauUpq4N8I'
import subprocess
subprocess.call("youtube-dl -F '%s'" %URL, shell=True)
print
# outlist numerical list of options
#input choice
Q = raw_input('Please select download quality from above ')
print 
# pass input Q (integer) to subprocess.call
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["youtube-dl -f "] + Q ,["'%s'" %URL], shell=True)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "./youtube.py", line 21, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["youtube-dl -f "] + Q ,["'%s'" %URL], shell=True)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

## subprocess.call is line 21

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you cannot concatenating a list (ex: `['foo', 'bar']`) to a string (ex: `'baz'`).  What you probably want to do is wrap your single argument in a list or more succintly, make it part of the original list:

(wrapping it in a list)

```
# SNIP
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["youtube-dl", "-f "] + [Q] + [URL])
```

(making it part of the original list

```
# SNIP
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', '-f', Q, URL])
```

Comment: drop `shell=True`, otherwise `-f`, etc are passed to the shell instead of `youtube-dl` program on Unix. It is almost always an error to use a list argument and `shell=True`.

Comment: `["youtube-dl -f "]` is incorrect. It should be `["youtube-dl", "-f"]`

Comment: +1. Also, in general I would use `check_call()`: errors shouldn't be ignored unless explicitely suppressed.